# can't able to call controller method based on the given url

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel framework. I have a problem while calling the method of controller class.

routes.php :

```
 Route::get('/', function()
{
  return View::make('hello');
});
```

It should call the view page of hello. It worked fine when giving the url **http://example.com/laravel**.

```
Route::get('home','HomeController@showWelcome')
```

When am provide the url like **http://example.com/laravel/home** it doesn't call the method of HomeController class.

HomeController.php :

```
 <?php

    class HomeController extends BaseController {

       public function showWelcome()
       {
           return View::make('hello');
       }

    }

 ?>
```

can anyone help me findout what mistake i did.. Thanks in advance.

**routes code look like below :**

```
 <?php
   Route::get('/', function()
   {
        return View::make('hello');
   });

   Route::get('home','HomeController@showWelcome');

?>
```

Comment: What happens with this route: `Route::get('/home/','HomeController@showWelcome')`  ?

Comment: Why is `*/laravel` going through the `'/'` route? (Are you using a route group with `laravel` as prefix or something?) If not, try `Route::get('laravel/home', 'HomeController@showWelcome');`

Comment: Can you add your routes code?

Comment: @Set Kyar Wa Lar:  I have posted route code above.. please check it out..

Comment: doesn't call the controller method name of **showWelcome**, when i give the url name of **home**

Comment: Now it's working fine when i use the url like **laravel/index.php/home**. But i don't want to use **index.php** in the url.

Answer (score 0):

The text below is from the Laravel Documentation:

**Apache**

The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the mod_rewrite module.

If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Nginx**

On Nginx, the following directive in your site configuration will allow "pretty" URLs:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: got the answser, when i use **laravel/index.php/home** in the url. But i don't want to use **index.php** in the url.. for that what can i do.

Comment: I updated the answer with the information you need based on Laravel installation page.